# Ms Access 2016 Hashtable cause Automation error

Tags: ms-access-2016

In our old system we were using ms access 2003
Now we move our system to ms access 2016 now we are getting Automation error 
when we debug;
msSqlAccessRelations.Add "CurrentUserId", "CurrentUserId"
this line gives an error.
we defined hashtable like this
Dim msSqlAccessRelations As New Hashtable
also mscorlib reference already added.

this code perfectly works on ms access 2003

```
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim msQry(0) As String
Dim accessQry(0) As String
Dim msSqlAccessRelations As New Hashtable
msQry(0) = "Select * From [IFSDB].[dbo].[Notes] Where ReferNum = " & ReferNum & " AND ReferTypeId = " & ReferTypeId & " " & extraFilter & " Order by NoteID desc"
accessQry(0) = "Select CurrentUserId , CurrentUserPrinted from TblCurrentUser"
msSqlAccessRelations.Add "CurrentUserId", "CurrentUserId"
If GetMSSQLDown = False Then
    Set GetNotes = GetDataToDifferentDb(msQry, accessQry, msSqlAccessRelations, "CurrentUserPrinted,Note,NoteID,CurrentUserId,ReferNum,ReferTypeId,AppearOnReport,AppearOnBOLReport,Date,ShowForPickers")
Else
    Set GetNotes = rs
End If
```

Comment: Works fine here, so something else is going on. Does your code compile?

Comment: Yes it is  compiled

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: [error Link](https://postimg.org/image/ihgbat965/)  @Gustav pleace check the link.

Comment: Seems like an installation issue rather than a code issue. Try to rewrite similar code in a new database. If it also fails, your install is hosed somehow.